# How to Replace failed HDD in HP ProLiant ML10 Gen 9 server which has Intel RST Raid-1 (Hardware Raid)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, restore, raid-1

we have HP server **HP ProLiant ML10 Gen 9** with **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS**. We have enabled Raid 1 for two HDD sized 2TB using Intel RST Raid configuration (which is an hardware raid).
Now one the Drive is failed and need to be replaced. I am doing this for the first time and dont have much knowledge on how to replace the HDD in the Raid 1 configuration.

Below is the output of the Raid Status ***cat /proc/mdstat***

```
surya@himalaya:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md126 : active raid1 sda[1] sdb[0]
      1953511424 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sda[1](S) sdb[0](S)
      6320 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

Below is the output of the HDD info ***lsblk***

```
surya@himalaya:~$ lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                         7:0    0 61.9M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1361
loop1                         7:1    0 67.9M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/22526
loop2                         7:2    0 55.5M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2284
loop3                         7:3    0 43.6M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/14978
loop4                         7:4    0 55.4M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2128
loop5                         7:5    0 43.6M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/15177
loop6                         7:6    0 67.2M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/21835
loop7                         7:7    0 61.9M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1376
sda                           8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
└─md126                       9:126  0  1.8T  0 raid1
  ├─md126p1                 259:0    0  1.1G  0 part  /boot/efi
  ├─md126p2                 259:1    0  1.5G  0 part  /boot
  └─md126p3                 259:2    0  1.8T  0 part
    ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  100G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-lv--0      253:1    0  1.7T  0 lvm   /home
sdb                           8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
└─md126                       9:126  0  1.8T  0 raid1
  ├─md126p1                 259:0    0  1.1G  0 part  /boot/efi
  ├─md126p2                 259:1    0  1.5G  0 part  /boot
  └─md126p3                 259:2    0  1.8T  0 part
    ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  100G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-lv--0      253:1    0  1.7T  0 lvm   /home
sr0                          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

As you can see in the above output, the drive **sdb** is the faulty one and need to be replaced.
it would be a great help if someone can help me with the steps on how to replace the faulty HDD to the new one.
FYI, this model doesn't support Hot plug HDD.

Comment: It should be enough to replace the faulty one and then use the tools of the RAID BIOS (CTRL + I) to rebuild the array.

Comment: Although not relevant to your question, FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Firmware-_and_driver-based